# r - Create a special counting table with variable thresholds

Tags: r, dataframe, count, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe named "data", as below :

| id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 5 |
| 02 | 3 |
| 03 | 7 |
| 04 | 4 |
| 05 | 9 |

and I would like to set thresholds and count how many ids are equal or below that threshold, which means a dataframe "results" like :

| threshold | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 10 | 5 |

The only way I found to do this is to use "for" :

`for(i in 1:10) {results$count[i] <- nrow(data[data$quantity <= i,]}`

This instruction does work. However, with my real data, there are 500 thresholds and I have to repeat quite the same process 12 times... thus the "for" loop is very long to proceed. I couldn't find something to replace that, I would rather something like :

`results$count <- nrow(data[data$quantity <= results$threshold,]`

but it doesn't work ("longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length").
Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~quantity,
  "01", 5,
  "02", 3,
  "03", 7,
  "04", 4,
  "05", 9
)

result <- map_dfr(1:10, function(x){
  tibble(
    threshold = x,
    count = sum(df$quantity <= x)
    )
})

result
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    threshold count
#>        <int> <int>
#>  1         1     0
#>  2         2     0
#>  3         3     1
#>  4         4     2
#>  5         5     3
#>  6         6     3
#>  7         7     4
#>  8         8     4
#>  9         9     5
#> 10        10     5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for! Thank you!